# Is it possible to install Scala on Windows without admin rights?

Tags: windows, scala, installation, admin, rights

I need only a folder where I could point Intellij Idea.
Could you please help? Probably exists another download like zip?

Previously it was possible. Not clear why I should install Scala only with admin rights. Does it require access to some admin functions?

Comment: Doesn't require root. Just download [this](http://www.scala-lang.org/download/) and extract it anywhere.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Admin permissions are not required to install scala. You can download different packages from [download page](http://www.scala-lang.org/download/2.11.7.html) (see at the bottom).

And if you are building project with **maven** or **sbt** they could download scala for you automatically and Idea can pick-up sdk from maven or ivy